# What AZ Services best for existing node API requires minimal retrofit effort?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-web-app-service

We have an existing node API backend project, planning to place it at Azure. It has its own structure

```
server.js
  |
  |-controller <folder>
  |-datamodel <folder>
  |-email <folder>
  |-middleware <folder>
  |-route <folder>
  |-...
```

server.js like

```
const fs = require("fs");
const mdw = require("./middleware/mdw");
const func1 = require("./func1/func1");
app.post('/upload', mdw.ValidateSession, func1);   
require("./route/myroute.js")(app);
```

myroute.js:

```
const objPS = require("../datamodel/mypostgresql");
module.exports = app =>
{
    const controller = require("../controller/mycontroller");
    app.post("/mypath/task1",   mdw.ValidateSession,    controller.dotask1); 
    ...
}
```

Typical IO in mycontroller:

```
exports.dotask1 = (req, res) =>
{
  ...
  if (err) res.status(500).send();
  else res.status(200).send(good);
}
```

New to Azure. Try to avoid **VM** as it requires additional manpower. **Function** svc has its own template and structure, may require some effort to redo this API to conform Azure Function. **Web App** Service clearly is not the way to go as it has no UI at all.

What AZ Services best for node API requires minimal retrofit effort?

Environment

```
Node v14
VSC v1.60 with latest Azure Tools and Docker extensions installed.
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try;

1. Static web apps (search for the one onside the storage account, and not the resource one…)
2. Function apps (I know, but it is the best for you…)